# Restore passphrase rsa/dsa keys

Tags: ssh, rsa, private-key, public-key, passphrase

I've installed new Ubuntu from scratch on my new machine and want to have an access to the remote host using `ssh`. The problem is that even if I have both public and private keys I forgot the passphrase used whilst creating keys because right after that I've passed it to `ssh-agent`. But I still have it (the `passphrase`) stored in the `ssh-agent` in my laptop. How can I restore the passphrase from `ssh-agent` if I have `root` access and both keys?

Comment: The ssh-agent would not survive a reboot. You never shutdown your laptop? Or mayby you are talking about a password manager such as gnome-keyring or KWallet ?

Comment: If ssh-agent stores passphrase only for a session then it must be somewhere else, because i can easily ssh into server w/o passphrase after reboot.

Comment: Already used a script to extract passwords from keyring, but i simply do not use it and response is `Extracting keys from "Session" keyring:
Keyring "Session" is empty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the passphrase is used to encrypt the private key. ssh-agent doesn't remember the passphrase - it remembers the decrypted private key.

And, as a damienfrancois mentioned, it shouldn't remember it past a reboot.

If you wished to extract the decrypted private keys from `ssh-agent` itself, you would have to find a tool written to search the memory of the running process and locate keys. One such tool can be found [here](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/breves/passe-partout.html.en), but you may well find it very challenging to use.

For a more practical answer, you can just delete your keys from `~/.ssh/id*`, make new ones that you know the passphrase for, and move on - for a new machine, you probably haven't gotten too reliant on them yet.

Comment: How is it possible that i do not enter a passphrase from my laptop but i need to do this with the same key from any other location?

Comment: When you enter the passphrase, it decodes the key. I assume something on your laptop (ssh-agent, gnome-keyright, idk) has cached that decrypted value.

Comment: You're probably right, but i can't get it why i could use key w/o passphrase easily while with it just failed.